# Docker with java sockets: data streams not recognized

Tags: java, docker, sockets, stream

I'm coding a client-server service where my server is sending files to the client.

In the following example, I tried to send a list of file names to my client.

**Server**

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4000);
connsock = serverSocket.accept();
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connsock.getOutputStream());

List<String> file_names = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage").listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        file_names.add(file.getName());
    }
}
objectOutput.writeObject(file_names);
objectOutput.flush();
```

**Client**

```
newclientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
objectInput1 = new ObjectInputStream(newclientSocket.getInputStream());

System.out.println("<---Available files--->");

// get list of files from server
Object file_names = objectInput1.readObject();
file_list = (ArrayList<String>) file_names;
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < file_list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(count + ")" + file_list.get(i));
    count++;
}
```

So when I run my program at *java NetBeans IDE* it works as I want. I get the files

```
<---Available files--->
1)blank.wav
2)fuark.wav
```

For the docker connection i created a network with

```
docker network create client_server_network
```

I run the server with

```
docker run --env SERVER_HOST_ENV=server --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it server
```

and the client with

```
docker run --network client_server_network -it clientimage
```

Although the *client-server connection is successful* through docker containers, when I run both services I don't get any output.

```
<---Available files--->
```

I'm stuck in this for days. What might be wrong? If I should provide any other information please tell me.

P.S. at the server-side of docker I set the *server* image as the host `newclientSocket = new Socket("server", 4000)`

Comment: Explain how you are running those client/server apps and how you are connecting them/to them.

Comment: @michalk you are right, updated